# sequence of conversions with contsructor-type conversions and conversion operators

Tags: c++, constructor, conversion-operator

I have read that a standard conversion can precede or follow a conversion implemented by a conversion operator or a contructor type conversion. On the other hand, 
a sequence of two conversion operators          is not allowed
a sequence of two contructor type conversions   is not allowed

I set out to test this and got a different result. I am using MSVC2010

In the first bunch code this fails: int b1 = sMe; which is great as it implies a sequence of two conversion operators: one from myString to myType and the other from myType to int

In the second bunch code this DOESNT fail: myString sYou(b); although I believe it implies a sequence of two constructor conversions: one from int to myType, the other  from myType to myString.

Can somebody explain to me what I am missing?

Many Thanks,

FIRST BUNCH

```
class myType {
public:
    myType(): val(10) {}
    myType(const myType &orig): val(orig.val) {}
    myType(int v1): val(v1) {} 

    bool hasSameValue(const myType &o2) {
        return (o2.val == val); }
    int getVal() {
        return val; }
    operator int() { return val; }

private:
    int val;

};


#include <string>
class myString {
public:
    myString(): val("I Dont Know you") {}
    myString(const myString &orig): val(orig.val) {}
    myString(myType v1): val("Really Dont know you") {} 

    bool hasSameValue(const myString &o2) {
        return (o2.val == val); }
    std::string getVal() {
        return val; }
    std::string getString() {return val;}

    operator myType() { return 1000; }


private:
    std::string val;

};




#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int b = 36;

    myString sMe;
    myString sYou(b);
    cout << "sYou: " << sYou.getString() << endl;
    cout << "sMe: " << sMe.getString() << endl;

    myType a = sMe;
    cout << a.getVal() << endl;
    int b1 = sMe;

    return 1;

}
```

SECOND BUNCH

```
class myType {
public:
    myType(): val(10) {}
    myType(const myType &orig): val(orig.val) {}
    myType(int v1): val(v1) {} 

    bool hasSameValue(const myType &o2) {
        return (o2.val == val); }
    int getVal() {
        return val; }

private:
    int val;

};


#include <string>
class myString {
public:
    myString(): val("I Dont Know you") {}
    myString(const myString &orig): val(orig.val) {}
    myString(myType v1): val("Really, I Dont Know you") {} 

    bool hasSameValue(const myString &o2) {
        return (o2.val == val); }
    std::string getVal() {
        return val; }
    std::string getString() {return val;}


private:
    std::string val;

};




#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    myType me;
    int a = 34;
    int b = 36;

    myType you(a);
    bool sameVal = you.hasSameValue(b);  
    cout << sameVal << endl;
    cout << "you: " << you.getVal() << endl;
    cout << "me: " << me.getVal() << endl;

    myString sMe;
    myString sYou(b);
    cout << "sYou: " << sYou.getString() << endl;
    cout << "sMe: " << sMe.getString() << endl;


    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myString sYou(b);` only involves one *implicit* conversion.  The second conversion is *explicit*; you're calling the constructor.  So it compiles.

Conversely, the following will *not* compile:

```
void func(myString blah) { ... }

func(b);
```

as this would require two implicit conversions.

Comment: Hi Oli, so essentially the fact that the operands are matched in the second conversion make it legal. Only a sequence of two constructor conversions are not legal obly when they are both implict. Is that correct?

Comment: @Random: That's exactly it.  The compiler will only make *one* implicit conversion in order to satisfy the argument list.

Comment: @oli: arent both conversions in the first bunch code also explicit because of the existence of the conversion operator? If that is correct, they still dont compile

Comment: @Random: "Implicit" in this context means that the compiler has to infer what to do from the context, rather than being explicitly told.  So in the first example, the compiler would have to infer `myString`->`myType`->`int`, whereas in the second example, it only has to infer `int`->`myType`.